# WCF callback not being executed

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I've been Googling this for a day now and can't seem to find the answer. Hoping someone can shed some light on this. I'm trying to implement a simple WCF client-server callback, with console apps at both the client and server sides. The operation executes on the server and everything seems to work fine except that the callback doesn't execute on the client. I.e. it never writes "Callback called!!!", and a breakpoint placed in the callback never trips. The client simply writes "Done." and waits for user input.

I'm sure it's something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
//SERVER CODE:
namespace NodeServiceLib
{
    public interface ISomeCallbackContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void OnCallback();
    }

    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ISomeCallbackContract))]
    public interface IMyContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoSomething();
    }

    public class NodeService : IMyContract
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something!!!");
        }
    }
}

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings/>
    <services>
      <service name="NodeServiceLib.NodeService" behaviorConfiguration="MEX">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/Node" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8001/Node" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint
          address="MyContract"
          binding="netTcpBinding"
          contract="NodeServiceLib.IMyContract"
        />
        <endpoint
          address="MEX"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"
        />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MEXGET">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="MEX">
          <serviceMetadata/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup</configuration>



//CLIENT CODE:
namespace TestConsole
{
    [CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
    class Callback : NodeServices.IMyContractCallback
    {
        public void OnCallback()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Callback called!!!");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // Give server time to spin up

            Console.WriteLine("=== CLIENT ===");

            InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(new Callback());
            NodeServices.MyContractClient proxy = new NodeServices.MyContractClient(context);
            proxy.DoSomething();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be calling the callback method in the server's DoSomething method?

Comment: Yeah, you'd think that would be obvious but the example I was working from made it look as though that was done automatically by WCF unless you wanted to override the concurrency mode. In retrospect, the solu5tion was simple: added 

[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]

to the service definition, and then 

 public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something!!!");
            ISomeCallbackContract callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISomeCallbackContract>();
            callback.OnCallback();
}

Thank you.